# What rounding method should I use for my case?

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I am building a class that will be required to round doubles.

In it, based on input *n*, it will (at max) have *n* decimal places and skip trailing zeroes if possible.

```
//If n = 2,

//1.697 -> 1.7  (instead of 1.70)     (edit)       
//1.000 -> 1    (instead of 1.00)             
//1.658 -> 1.66
```

There seems to be numerous rounding techniques but I'm not sure which one is applicable for my case.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Why would 1.693 be rounded to 1.7 and not to 1.69?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: The examples are RoundingMode.UP which is not the norm RoundingMode.HALF_UP: the superfluous digit being 5-9 rounding up, 0-4 rounding down. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Note: `1 == 1.00` the values is the same, the only difference is how you choose to format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about DecimalFormatting here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Although your question is a bit confusing. Why round 1.693 to 1.7 but then 1.658 to 1.66.
You're rounding different in both.

Comment: As many comments stated, I intended to round to 2 places: 1.69. By mistake I rounded to 1.7

Comment: @user2999870 decimal formatting is what you'd want then!